# strtok with string literal as parameter

Tags: c

Why does compiling with -Wpedantic warn about assignment from incompatible pointer type when passing a string literal as the second parameter to `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);`, and what can be done about it?

Comment: @WeatherVane: It doesn't write to the second parameter though. The OP is specifically saying the compiler is flagging the *second* parameter, the delimiter, which is marked `const`. We need a [MCVE].

Comment: the second argument shouldn't be a problem. Can you share the code snippet which triggers the error?

Comment: Please show example code.

Comment: Please show the actual code.  There shouldn't be a problem — so you're doing something unusual.  It shouldn't be very big — much 10 lines would be a surprise — so you'll be creating a nice MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: It shouldn't.  Rather than describe the code, **show the code**.

Comment: @ShadowRanger two of us misread it - but it is usual to use a string literal as the second parameter.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yeah. It was my first thought as well as soon as I saw "`strtok`" and "string literal" together in a post. Without code, we'll never know.

Comment: If it were the const thing, it would be `-Wwrite-strings`, not `-Wpedantic`, the error message would say `discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type` (not incompatible pointer type), and it wouldn't mention "assignment".

Answer (score 1):

Since the warning reads: "**Assignment** from incompatible pointer type", the problem must be the left side of the assignment from strtok, for example like this:

```
int *foo;
foo = strtok(s, ",");
```

You have to make sure, that the left side of your assignment has a compatible pointer type, for example `char *` or `void *`.